# Unable to access LAN devices

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ping

A bit a of a newbie to anything network related so bear with me here.

I'm having trouble having a reliable SSH connection to my Raspberry Pi servers on my local network.
Say I am running a minecraft server or a web server (say it was 192.168.1.111).
I use CMD on my windows machine to ping the server (`ping 192.168.1.111`).
When I get a successful reply, then I connect to it via SSH or other means.

But more often times than not, when I ping them or attempt to SSH into them, I get a "`Destination host unreachable`" or "`Connection timed out`".
But when I reboot my router, it works perfectly fine for a while.

When I run "`arp -a`" on my CMD it sometimes shows.

My thoughts are that this is an issue with my router because ping and SSH replies are also the same when I use other devices.

This is truly frustrating.
Thank you for your time

[Here is the requested screenshot of how if I reboot my routed and everything works properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW8NV.png)

Comment: First item to raise:  The two IP addresses you share are different (192.168.1.111 and 192.169.1.111).  Can you share a screenshot of the successful ping followed by the ssh command, including error?  If there is room in the screenshot, the output of the arp command might be interesting.

Comment: Sorry about that! Its supposed to be '192.168.1.111' I have corrected it now.
I have also added the photo of a screenshot

Comment: I find my PI thinks it does not always have Internet. I may have to quit the browser and start the browser back up to get Internet. It is not used as a server so it does not matter much. Try restarting it when you need it, wait 60 seconds and see if internet is always available that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my ISP provided router. For some reason it blocked a bunch of stuff on my local network. I got rid of that one and got an Archer A9 and everything works perfectly fine.

I really don't understand why ISP routers are like this. If anyone has an answer please feel free to let me know

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the IP as a static one on the device? Is the same IP also distributed by your router with DHCP? Because the output of your „arp -a“ shows that’s a dynamic one. So I assume you have IP conflicts in your network. Check which ip range gets distributed by your router and which IP’s you can use to set as static ones.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer
The IP is a static one, I set the ip as ip 111, 112, and 113 for my Raspberry Pi so that its easier to remember. I'm looking on the router's connected devices and it shows that there are no other devices set as those IPs, so I assume I'm in the clear?
Also I'm pretty sure they'll still show up as dynamic in arp -a regardless if I set it as static on my router or not.

Comment: You are not fully in the clear. Your router distributes some IP’s with DHCP. It’s possible that these IP’s (f.e. your raspberry pi’) is in this range. So it’s possible that you will get/have got an IP conflict if your router distributes this IP. (Same IP for two different devices)

Comment: I've checked all my router settings and there doesn't seem to have any conflicts.
I still dont understand what is going on

Comment: Can you provide some images of your settings?

Comment: Settings of...
Of the list of connected devices? My DHCP settings?

Comment: Yes of the DHCP settings and the connected devices. Also the configuration files of your devices (if they exist). Do you have any network Switches in your network?